# How to configure mamp to use mariadb on mac os 2022

Tags: mysql, nginx, mariadb, webserver, mamp

I am currently using mamp with nginx and mysql but my project uses features only available in mariadb

i found an answer from 2011 but the solution is outdated and did not work for me is there a way to replace the currently installed mysql with mariadb in mamp for mac os?

Comment: You could run a MariaDB container on mac os. Or use [wamp](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/wamp/) that includes MariaDB.

Comment: wamp only runs on windows i am using a mac, i just wanted to swap out the mysql for mariadb and use my existing mamp nginx setup